# Comment to url API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using Facebook Comments plugin in my website:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/

by add this to my web :

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://example.com" data-num-posts="2" data-width="470"></div>
```

And i want to use it also in my android app, Can i use Facebook API or something else that i can make a comment on a URL without using the Comment plug-in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its impossible but comment plugin will show mobile version automatically for mobile devices

> The mobile version will automatically show up when a mobile device
>   user agent is detected. You can turn this behavior off by setting the
>   mobile parameter to false. Please note: the mobile version ignores the
>   width parameter, and instead has a fluid width of 100% in order to
>   resize well in portrait/landscape switching situations. You may need
>   to adjust your CSS for your mobile site to take advantage of this
>   behavior. If preferred, you can still control the width via a
>   container element.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Graph API with `stream_publish` permission from the user in order to publish comments on their behalf. You can read the following docs to see how that works:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/#comments

Comment: This is about commenting on posts not in comment plugin